# What are ClearClick and ABE?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, clear-net, settings

I'm new to Tor. What is Application Boundaries Enforcer (ABE) and ClearClick and why should I have them turned on or off?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ABE and ClearClick are part of the NoScript add-on.

**ClearClick**

Clickjacking is a method of tricking you into clicking something you probably didn't want to click on. There's various ways to clickjack, but most of them use iFrames or JavaScript to partially cover a link or button, so you accidentally click on the "bad" link instead of what you thought you were clicking on.

ClearClick automatically detects clickjacking attempts, and shows you a warning. For exact details, read the FAQ here: https://noscript.net/faq#qa7_4

**ABE**

ABE is the Application Boundaries enforcer, and protects against cross-site request forgery, or CSRF. It basically blocks websites from accessing resources on your local network. More detailed information is available on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSRF

Both of these features help keep you safer, so it's probably best to keep them turned on.

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear explanations and sources. I turned both of them on now. I'm curious though if I should also turn on the option to allow sites to push their own rulesets?

Comment: I can't find anything about it in the FAQ, so this is just my opinion now. I'd leave it disabled (default). It looks like it would only work if a website is set up for NoScript users, and a malicious website could misuse that ability. Most websites work just fine without special ABE rules anyway.